unique home pages for two sites
I have a single instance of docusaurus and I want to create two sites (site A and site B). There are "documents" that are shared between sites. I have create two different "docusaurus.config.js" files, so that they can have different titles, tags, sidebars, etc.
The issue is that both sites will use the same homepage in /src/pages/index.js. I have found that I can create separate markdown pages with the slug: / will work, but that also includes a sidebar menu, breadcrumbs, etc which I don't want.
It is possible to have the "docusaurus.config.js" to specify different home pages. for example site A would use the /src/pages/site_A-homepage/index.js and site B would use /src/pages/site_B-homepage/index.js

Can you just add an additional docs directory? This allows for a second "site."
This is called a docs "multi-instance."
Follow this: Is there a way to have two docs in Docusaurus 2?
There's official documentation for this, too: https://docusaurus.io/docs/docs-multi-instance
